# Using regular expressions to search a word list. Finding 2 letter words instead of 3. Why?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I am studying regular expressions and I am stumped. Here is my process so far....

I downloaded this file.

```
wget http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt
mv corncob_lowercase.txt words.txt
```

I wanted all 3 letter words...

```
grep '^...$' words.txt
```

This DOES finds "abe"

```
grep '^abe.$' words.txt
```

This does NOT find "abe"

```
grep '^abe$' words.txt
```

This DOES find "abe" in the library that came with Arch Linux.

```
grep '^abe$' /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small
```

I am stumped on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ file corncob_lowercase.txt 
corncob_lowercase.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Probably the DOS line endings are the source of your problem.  CR is counting as a character for at least some purposes.

Run it through `dos2unix`, or `tr -d '\r'`, before `grep`ing.

Comment: The problem, as far as I can tell, was the line-breaks. Since I created a new file with dos2unix and just the default mode -ascii (which convert only line breaks) and this file was sound.

I then used tr -d '\r' and that worked also.

The tr is translate command. ( This looks useful! )
The -d is the delete option. 
The '\r' is the return set. So it removes returns (line-break).

Comment: yep, `tr -d '\r'` does the same thing as dos2unix, except it also removes CRs ('\r') that don't precede NLs ('\n").  Usually sed, awk, or even perl are better options that stringing together multiple tr / grep / cut / whatever other commands.  But in this case, it does the job in one invocation, and is available everywhere.